# Adding a .deb file to debian package as dependency

Tags: debian, packaging

I am trying to package a program (FCL) but it has a dependency - libccd - which I had to package myself. So now I have created a `libccd_2.0-1.deb` file using check-install and I would like it to be installed as FCL dependency. So I added `libccd (>= 1.0)`  in the control file of FCL Debian package. But the FCL package is complaining that it can't find the dependency `libccd`.

How can I make FCL package install the `libccd_2.0-1.deb` when it sees the dependency `libccd`? Also, where should I add the `.deb` file in the FCL Debian package?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.
`dpkg` (which is used for installing individual .deb files) cannot fullfil dependencies.

Dependencies can be resolved only by `apt-get` / `aptitude`, but they cannot install `.deb` files directly, they can install packages only from repositories. Each repository has a metadata file and apt build its knowledge database, so when dependency says package `libccd` is needed, it will know that is available from repository XY.

But `dpkg` doesn't know where to search for needed packages. You can install your packages either by installing the `libccd*.deb` first, then by installing the `fcl*.deb` itself. Or preferably you can put them both as parameters of one dpkg call like this: `dpkg -i fcl*.deb libccd*.deb` and dpkg will figure itself which of those 2 to install first. (Or you can create your own repository where you will have both packages with related metadata.)

Comment: i usually install individual .deb files using Ubuntu software center, which will install all the dependencies also

Comment: (don't know if they internal use aptitude though)

Comment: That is a GUI frontend to aptitude/dpkg, so I guess it parses the dependencies from dpkg output, installs them via aptitude and then installs the .deb file via dpkg.

Comment: the dependency resolving system is called `apt`, with `apt-get` and `aptitude` (and `synaptics` and what not) being front-ends.

Answer (score 1):

Since apt version 1.1 (currently in Debian experimental), you can actually install .deb files directly using:

```
% sudo apt-get install ./disorderfs_0.1.0-1_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'disorderfs' instead of 'disorderfs_0.1.0-1_amd64.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fuse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  disorderfs fuse
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 70.8 kB/81.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 175 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```